# How to compare and validate the requested URL with a custom URL string?

Tags: javascript, express, ecmascript-6

I have a route that goes to the index page. I have a secret token that allows access to this page. I want to compare the requested URL with a custom string. The current URL in use is `http://localhost:3000/?token=secret` but if I enter `http://localhost:3000/as?token=secret` it doesn't render the 404 error page that I created, instead says `Cannot GET /as`. I wondering how to validate this and render out the error page correctly

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.url); // /?token=secret
    if (req.url !== `/?token=${websocket_token}`) {
        res.render('error', {
            title: '404 Not Found',
            errorMessage: '404 Not Found'
        });
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: That makes no sense at all. Are you changing the request somewhere in middleware or something? You are going to `/helloworld` you say. Not `/as`.

Comment: @CharlieFish no sorry I have changed it

Comment: Oh got it. One second while I write up an answer.

Comment: I assume you are interested in query string which you can get by req.query prop in express. Make middleware, before your route-s, that handle and check query string and just if pass that middlware user will be able to see your routes.

Comment: @Deathmras `req.url` will work too. See https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url. It includes the query string as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Express each `app.get` or other related method handles it's own route. So when you do `app.get('/'` you are only matching routes that are `/` not `/as`.

You could change it to `*` to match all routes. Maybe like the following?

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.url); // /?token=secret
    if (req.url !== `/?token=${websocket_token}`) {
        res.render('error', {
            title: '404 Not Found',
            errorMessage: '404 Not Found'
        });
        return;
    }
});
```

Or of course you could have a dedicated section for your 404 messages.

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.url); // /?token=secret
    if (req.url !== `/?token=${websocket_token}`) {
        return next();
    }
    // Valid request
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('error', {
        title: '404 Not Found',
        errorMessage: '404 Not Found'
    });
});
```

At the end of the day there are so many ways you can handle Express routing. It's very powerful and flexible.

I'd suggest you look [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/faq.html) under the `How do I handle 404 responses?` section for another idea as well.

---

Also, remember, having secrets in a URL like that, probably isn't the most secure thing. So there are a lot of reasons I wouldn't suggest this for security reasons. But just answering your question, the above should work.

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way to handle 404s in Express is to register your *final* route handler with the `use` method rather than using one of the HTTP-specific methods.

```
app.use((req, res) => {
  res.render('error', {
    title: '404 not found',
    errorMessage: '404 not found'
  })
})
```

I emphasize the word *final* because `use` registers a catch-all handler, so this will override any route that it precedes in your code. If all your other routes are registered before this, then this will catch any request that has not matched any other route – regardless of the HTTP method that was used. So this will apply to any GET, POST, PUT, DELETE request.

An even more idiomatic way in Express to handle 404s (and all HTTP error responses) is to use the `next` argument that comes with all route handlers. This will re-route the request to the next handler that specifically takes an error as it's first argument:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new Error('404 not found')
  error.statusCode = 404
  next(error)
})

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(error.status || 500)
  res.render('error', {
    title: error.message,
    errorMessage: error.message
  })
})
```

This is great because you now have a generic error handler, which you can access from inside any other route. So this will handle not only 404s, but also 401s, 403s, 503s, anything you want that doesn't render successfully for the user. And you can access this route simply by calling `next` with an error as the first argument from inside any other route handler.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `passport-auth-token` for validating the token & display success or error pages.

**Configure Strategy**

The token authentication strategy authenticates users using a token. The strategy requires a verify callback, which accepts these credentials and calls done providing a user.

```
passport.use('authtoken', new AuthTokenStrategy(
  function(token, done) {
    AccessToken.findOne({
      id: token
    }, function(error, accessToken) {
      if (error) {
        return done(error);
      }

      if (accessToken) {
        if (!token.isValid(accessToken)) {
          return done(null, false);
        }

        User.findOne({
          id: accessToken.userId
        }, function(error, user) {
          if (error) {
            return done(error);
          }

          if (!user) {
            return done(null, false);
          }

          return done(null, user);
        });
      } else {
        return done(null);
      }
    });
  }
));
```

**Authenticate Requests**

Use `passport.authenticate()`, specifying the `'authtoken'` strategy, to authenticate requests.

For example, as route middleware in an Express application:

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate(
    'authtoken',
    {
      session: false,
      optional: false
    }
  ),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
);
```